# Why the soul comes in through the nose and comes out through the mouth?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parts-of-the-body, soul, adam

1. G-d blows the soul in through the nostrils, not his mouth:

> וַיִּיצֶר ה"א אֶת־הָאָדָם עָפָר מִן־הָאֲדָמָה וַיִּפַּח בְּאַפָּיו נִשְׁמַת חַיִּים וַיְהִי הָאָדָם לְנֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה׃
>
> the LORD God ... blew into his nostrils the breath of life, and man became a living being.

2. G-d sucks the soul out through the [kiss on the] mouth: The verses about the way of death of Moses, Aharon and Miriam ([here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.34.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Targum&lang2=en))

> "וַיָּמָת שָׁם מֹשֶׁה עֶבֶד־ה' בְּאֶרֶץ מוֹאָב עַל־פִּי ה' " - literally "by the mouth [on mouth] of G-d"

According to the sources [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93180/15579), it hints that their souls were "sucked out" through the kiss on the mouth.

This looks contradicting to me - this could be the other way around either. Any explanations?

Comment: Because breathing usually takes place through the nostrils. At death, the (facial) muscles relax, and the mouth (slightly) opens.

Answer (score 1):

Another user answered [a different question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31366/why-nostrils-and-not-mouth?rq=1) with the following:

> Because the soul enters and exits the body via the nose. In the
> Midrash "Pirkei Rebbi Eliezer" it says that from the beginning of
> creation nobody became ill, but instead a person would sneeze and his
> soul would exit from his nostrils, until Yaakov came along and asked
> Hashem for mercy - that He shouldn't take his soul until he has time
> to command his offspring how to conduct themselves after he is dead.
> Hashem accepted his request, as it says [Bereishis
> 48,1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0148.htm#1) "And it was after
> these things that Yosef was told: Behold! (something unusual!), your
> father is sick", something which had never occurred from the days of
> creation!
>
> The Midrash concludes that therefore when a person sneezes one should
> wish him life (health) because sneezing used to signify the opposite
> of life. This is the source of saying Bless You or Gesundheit or
> לבריות or something similar in different languages.

I believe your premise is unfounded; while those few individuals did merit a special death via a Divine "kiss" that is not the general way the soul leaves the body.

Comment: +1 Good point, can you find this PrDR"E Midrash, please.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.52.6?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: Great, So you're saying according to this Midrash, that Moses' and Aharon's the מיתת נשיקה was exceptional. Interesting.

Comment: Absolutely. See the gemara in Bava Batra for one example (https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.17a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and Rabbeinu Bachya (https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.34.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Devarim.34.5.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en).

Answer (score -2):

Because the nose is the only open part of the body which can not do a sin (sans the smelling of idol worship).

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. You should also add sources to explain why you chose this answer.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!